# AX 2009 Import/Export via Administration vs table preservation for data refresh

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, data-import, data-export

I'm just a SQL guy, so forgive me is this is a dumb question, or in the wrong place.

My instructions for a data refresh from production to the lower environments have me going into the AX client and backing up 8 tables to a file via pointy-clicky mouse action:

- EmplTable
- SysUserProfiles
- SysUserInfo
- SysCompanyUserInfo
- DirPartyTable
- EmployeeTypes
- UserGroupList
- UserInfo

Then, I stop the AOS's and do what I do best -- use some SQL to copy data out of 31 tables and into a safe place, do the database restore, copy the data back into the 31 tables from the safe place. Then Start the AOS's, sync the dictionaries, and finally import the 8 tables via the AX client (all pointy-clicky like).

I can sync from the command line. I can preserve 31 tables via sql from the command line. I can start and stop AOS's in the right order from the command line. But I can't do this AX Export/Import Tables step and with three environments all that pointy-clicky angers me.

Question, Finally: What happens on export/import in the client, if anything, that wouldn't be covered by just dealing with those 8 tables like the other 31? Is it something a dict sync wouldn't fix? Is there a way to tell what it might also do? Is there a simple way in X++ to code the export/import? I already kind of have a grasp on sysStartupCmd and how to get stuff to happen from ax32.exe -StartupCmd , but honestly SQL is so much easier for me, being my native tongue.

Thanks for reading all that!

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you do the pointy-click action? This almost sounds like you are exporting the XPO, which would be just the table schema, not the actual data.

Comment: Pretty sure it's actually data. " go to Administration > Periodic > Data export/import > Export to, select *Users definition group, click the export to button, save the export to somewhere you will be able to access later (file type binary), click the OK button when asked if you want to export one or more of the user related tables." * - The 8 tables are from a part that says how to create the Users definition group. I just noticed that it creates a DEF and a DAT file.

Comment: import instructions (condensed) : Go to Administration > Periodic > Data export/import > Import, Select the data file that you exported earlier, click the Advanced tab, Make sure the “Include system and shared tables” checkbox is checked, make sure the “Use Record ID Compression” checkbox is unchecked, make sure the “Update existing records” radio button is selected, and make sure Indexing is set to “Update index continuously…”, Click the OK button, At the “Delete Following Tables” window, make sure no tables are selected and click OK, On the “Update” dialog, click Yes

Comment: Why are you exporting 8+31 tables worth of data from lower (test/dev?) environments, then replacing with live data, then dumping that back over? Are they staging environments for data changes you are planning to make to live? Those 8 tables you have listed seem odd to me. `DirPartyTable` is used to connect locations (addresses) to party entities (customers, vendors, contacts, etc). So why would you want to replace live data with seemingly stale data?  And one of the  `UserInfo/SysUserInfo` stores data from Admin>Users. So do you enable/disable a different set of users in lower environments?

Comment: I don't think he's replacing the data from production, but adding to it. Probably because some users (e.g. developers) are not set up in the production environment. The usage of the Data export/import functionality could be motivated by RecId references in these tables. It can be automated with `SysStartupCmd`, but that would need some customization.

Comment: Alex Kwitny - We take a refresh backup from production, export tables from the target env, turn off all aos servers in the target env, restore the entire database to the target env, restore the 8+31 preserved tables back and then start aos's. There is a substantial amount of configuration information in SQL, straight restoring a backup to a lower environment would essentially turn that environment into production. Just as an example, SysEmailParameters is kept empty so test, dev, training can't send emails. Yes, different env's have different users, dev doesn't have access to test or prod...

Comment: FH-Inway "could be motivated by RecId references in these tables." Isn't RecId in the tables though? A dev here speculated the same thing. (yes, I asked internally but no one seems to have an answer.) "some users are not set up in ... production" Isn't this pretty normal? I'd question sanity of any company letting developers access test or production... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process you described seems somewhat unusual for an update process, but it makes sense in certain contexts.

As it was stated in a comment, you are basically preserving data for your lower environment. The process you described in the comments updates existing records with the old data, while keeping the new data. If you wanted to attempt this via SQL, you would need to write it as an upsert (as new records may be created while existing records would be updated). It looks like the tables are all related to users in some manner, so this process would make sense if there is a different set of users from production to your lower environment, which is not unusual, especially in a SOX regulated environment. A Data Dictionary sync wouldn't really do anything in this situation - that basically just updates the table schema in SQL to match the definition stored in AX. Since that schema hasn't changed, nothing would happen.

With the other (31) tables you mention, it sounds like you're doing more of a table replacement (so the table is truncated prior to inserting the new data, or the data from the restore process is otherwise discarded/ignored), which is why the process may be different from the 8 user tables.

In any case, to answer your question directly, I don't know of any out-of-the-box process that could automate this for you. The `StartupCmd=` flag, would be the logical place to look for this, but the only import command available is for XPO (code) files. If you wanted something to automate the process, you would need to create a new class that extends `SysStartupCmd` and would call the same functions you would normally do manually. This wouldn't be difficult, but would take a little bit of research to determine the commands and parameters used. You can look at the `SysStartupCmdAOTImport` class to get an idea of how it would be structured. The import process seems to be controlled from the `SysDataImport` class, so look at that to mimic the user input or to see exactly what the process does.

If you are looking for an alternative (automated) process, consider that when I do a data update of our environments (we have some environments that update every day, some that update a couple times a month, others whenever we feel it's needed, all 100% automated), we simply run a SQL script that updates or creates the necessary records after the backup is restored. The values are essentially hard-coded into the script, but since they don't change it's not a  big deal. The downside of this technique compared to yours, is that if we have a user that needs access only to a non-production environment, they must first be in the production environment (disabled), and then the script updates the necessary values the next time the target environment is updated. Additionally, your system developers/administrators would need to be sure to communicate any changes that would need to be made to the script (for example, if new table values need to be changed or a new set of user permissions), which adds some overhead to the process.

Comment: I think my question, now that I've written it all out, is just "Does Importing Data via Administration in the AX32.exe client do anything beyond take data from a file and dump it into tables row by row via an upsert?" and as a follow up, "Is there a way to tell what it might also do?" We've extended SysStartupCmd to create AOTExport, so I am very familiar with that process, but I don't exactly know how to figure out what this Import command actually does. I'll add bounty to this question in 6 hours when it is eligible, thanks.

Comment: With a quick look, it looks like the `Administration \ Periodic \ Data export/import \ Import` function is just a call to `SysDataImport.main()`. I would image all you need to do is construct a new instance of that class, set the necessary args (see `getFromDialog` for what the user dialog normally sets), and then call `run` in your `SysStartupCmd` class. Reading more into `SysDataImport` can also probably answer your question on exactly what the process does.